# Обращение к элементам Fragment'ов внутри ViewPager из родительской Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, android-viewpager

Есть родительское Activity, в котором находятся ViewPager и FAB:

```
public class SelectedRankingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private String rankingType;
private Toolbar tb;
private ViewPager vpSelectedRanking;
private ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
private FloatingActionButton fab;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_selected_ranking);

    rankingType = getIntent().getStringExtra("rankingType");

    tb = findViewById(R.id.toolbarSelectedRankingActivity);
    tb.setTitle(rankingType);
    tb.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            finish();
        }
    });
    vpSelectedRanking = findViewById(R.id.ViewPagerSelectedRankingActivity);
    vpSelectedRanking.setOffscreenPageLimit(6);

    fillViewPager();
    vpSelectedRanking.setAdapter(adapter);

    fab = findViewById(R.id.fabSelectedRankingViewPager);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });
}

private void fillViewPager() {
    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    switch (rankingType) {
        case "Uci World Ranking":
            adapter.addFragment(new ViewPagerSelectedFragment(rankingType,getString(R.string.individual)), getString(R.string.individual));
            adapter.addFragment(new ViewPagerSelectedFragment(rankingType,getString(R.string.teams)), getString(R.string.teams));
            adapter.addFragment(new ViewPagerSelectedFragment(rankingType,getString(R.string.nations)), getString(R.string.nations));
            break;
        case "Rider specialties":
            adapter.addFragment(new ViewPagerSelectedFragment(rankingType,getString(R.string.gc_ranking)), getString(R.string.gc_ranking));
            adapter.addFragment(new ViewPagerSelectedFragment(rankingType,getString(R.string.sprinters)), getString(R.string.sprinters));
            adapter.addFragment(new ViewPagerSelectedFragment(rankingType,getString(R.string.climbers_ranking)), getString(R.string.climbers_ranking));
            adapter.addFragment(new ViewPagerSelectedFragment(rankingType,getString(R.string.time_trial)), getString(R.string.time_trial));
            adapter.addFragment(new ViewPagerSelectedFragment(rankingType,getString(R.string.prologues)), getString(R.string.prologues));
            adapter.addFragment(new ViewPagerSelectedFragment(rankingType,getString(R.string.one_day_races)), getString(R.string.one_day_races));
            break;
        case "Pcs Ranking":
            adapter.addFragment(new ViewPagerSelectedFragment(rankingType,getString(R.string.individual)), getString(R.string.individual));
            adapter.addFragment(new ViewPagerSelectedFragment(rankingType,getString(R.string.teams)), getString(R.string.teams));
            adapter.addFragment(new ViewPagerSelectedFragment(rankingType,getString(R.string.nations)), getString(R.string.nations));
            adapter.addFragment(new ViewPagerSelectedFragment(rankingType,getString(R.string.u23)), getString(R.string.u23));
            adapter.addFragment(new ViewPagerSelectedFragment(rankingType,getString(R.string.u23_nations)), getString(R.string.u23_nations));
            adapter.addFragment(new ViewPagerSelectedFragment(rankingType,getString(R.string.races)), getString(R.string.races));
            break;
        case "Pcs Season":
            adapter.addFragment(new ViewPagerSelectedFragment(rankingType,getString(R.string.individual)), getString(R.string.individual));
            adapter.addFragment(new ViewPagerSelectedFragment(rankingType,getString(R.string.teams)), getString(R.string.teams));
            adapter.addFragment(new ViewPagerSelectedFragment(rankingType,getString(R.string.nations)), getString(R.string.nations));
            adapter.addFragment(new ViewPagerSelectedFragment(rankingType,getString(R.string.distance)), getString(R.string.distance));
            adapter.addFragment(new ViewPagerSelectedFragment(rankingType,getString(R.string.racedays)), getString(R.string.racedays));
            break;
        case "Pcs Wins":
            adapter.addFragment(new ViewPagerSelectedFragment(rankingType,getString(R.string.individual)), getString(R.string.individual));
            adapter.addFragment(new ViewPagerSelectedFragment(rankingType,getString(R.string.individual_1_plus)), getString(R.string.individual_1_plus));
            adapter.addFragment(new ViewPagerSelectedFragment(rankingType,getString(R.string.teams)), getString(R.string.teams));
            adapter.addFragment(new ViewPagerSelectedFragment(rankingType,getString(R.string.nations)), getString(R.string.nations));
            break;
        case "Specials":
            adapter.addFragment(new ViewPagerSelectedFragment(rankingType,getString(R.string.all_time)), getString(R.string.all_time));
            adapter.addFragment(new ViewPagerSelectedFragment(rankingType,getString(R.string.rider_popularity)), getString(R.string.rider_popularity));
            break;
    }
}
```

В этом же Activity мы заполняем ViewPager фрагментами(У меня один xml шаблон для всех фрагментов).
Код фрагмента:

```
public class ViewPagerSelectedFragment extends Fragment {

private String rankingType;
private String rankingClass;
private RecyclerView rvRanking;
private TextView tv;

public ViewPagerSelectedFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public ViewPagerSelectedFragment(String rt, String rc) {
    rankingType = rt;
    rankingClass = rc;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_pager_selected, container, false);

    tv = v.findViewById(R.id.textView3);

    return v;
}

public void setTv() {
    tv.setText(rankingClass + "--" + rankingType);
}
```

Вопрос в том, как по нажатию на FAB изменять содержимое видимого в данный момент фрагмента?
Пробовал так:

```
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ViewPagerSelectedFragment fragment = vpSelectedRanking.getCurrentItem();
        }
    });
```

И так:

```
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ViewPagerSelectedFragment fragment = adapter.getItem(vpSelectedRanking.getCurrentItem());
        }
    });
```

Но так и не понял как изменять содержимое отдельного фрагмента из Activity через FAB.
Скриншот Activity.xml:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скриншот Fragment.xml:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Update: ViewPager adapter

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

private final ArrayList<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
private final ArrayList<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

public ViewPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT);
}

public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
    mFragmentList.add(fragment);
    mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return mFragmentList.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFragmentList.size();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
}
```

Comment: Ваш fragment уже приведен к типу ViewPagerSelectedFragment, ну так и воспользуйтесь public методом, например: fragment.setTv()

Comment: Я не могу обратиться к setTv, так, как вы написали.

Comment: ViewPager.getCurrentItem выдает номер текущей страницы. А где вы взяли ViewPagerAdapter? Покажите реализацию.

Comment: Добавил код адаптера

Comment: `ViewPagerSelectedFragment fragment = (ViewPagerSelectedFragment) adapter.getItem(vpSelectedRanking.getCurrentItem());`

Comment: а вам не легче использовать фрагменты? неужели у вас одинаковые страницы будут?